# graphic explanation to Dini's theorem

Tags: real-analysis

> Consider equation $x^2+y^2=0, (x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$. Explain by
>   graphing the set of solutions, why the conclusion of Dini's theorem
>   does not hold at the solution (0,0).

**My attempt:**
Let $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$, then $f(0,0)=0$,
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=0$, 
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$, so the assumptions of Dini's theorem do not hold.

The set of solutions consists of only one point $(0,0).$ But how does that explain that Dini's theorem does not hold?

Comment: Which theorem do you have in mind? It doesn't seem that it is [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem).

Comment: It's the Implicit Function theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really give more than this Hint without solving the Problem for you:

Stare long enough at the CONCLUSION of the Implicit function theorem

Comment: if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \neq 0$, then there is a nbhd where $y$ is locally a function of $x$? Am I in the right direction?

Comment: I don't know what nbhd means, and of course in your case $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$ as you stated above. Could you elaborate? It's about what f and g should fullfill if you use the implicit function theorem.

Comment: nbhd - neighborhood. There is continuously differentiable function $g:I \rightarrow \mathbb R$, where $I$ is an open interval, such that f(x, g(x))=0?

Comment: exactly, now you got it.

Comment: sorry, I still dont get, how this is related to the graph of solutions? There is no open interval?

Comment: Take an open intervall around zero. Take some x in this intervall which is nonzero (which has to exist in the open intervall around zero of course). Compute f(x,g(x)). Why can this not be 0? Maybe you didn't see that $f(x,g(x))=0$ has to hold for all x in the open intervall

Comment: It cant be 0, because the only solution is (0,0), right?

Comment: Exactly. you could even compute this. $f(x,g(x)) = x^2 + g(x)^2 >0$ because $x != 0$ implies $x^2 > 0$ and $g(x)^2 > 0$